# App not working after IOS version update to IOS 15

Tags: ios, react-native

I am facing these issues in react native app :

1. After updating the react native to updated version from 0.63.3 to 0.64.1 project is not running in iOS
2. After IOS 15 update the app shows the error “The developer of the app needs to update it to work with this version of iPadOS” ( for both - React native version 0.64.1 and React native version 0.63.3)

[Additional details currently minimum deployment version for ios is iOS 10.]

Answer (score 1):

I think all you'll need to do is update Xcode and build/compile using Xcode 13. You can verify your command line tools are using the correct version of Xcode by opening up the Xcode application, selecting Preferences and then viewing Command Line Tools under the Locations tab. If everything looks good, restart any terminals currently running to ensure they use the latest changes.

[image]

Be sure any remote build services (App Center, Expo EAS, etc) are set to use Xcode 13 as well